# How can I recursively copy same-named files from one directory structure to another in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two directories, say `dir1` and `dir2`, that have exactly the same directory structure. How do I recursively copy all the `*.txt` files from `dir1` to `dir2`?

Example:

I want to copy from

```
dir1/subdir1/file.txt
dir1/subdir2/someFile.txt
dir1/.../..../anotherFile.txt
```

to

```
dir2/subdir1/file.txt
dir2/subdir2/someFile.txt
dir2/.../..../anotherFile.txt
```

The `.../...` in the last file example means this could be any sub-directory, which can have sub-directories itself.

Again I want to do this programmatically. Here's the pseudo-code

```
SRC=dir1
DST=dir2
for f in `find ./$SRC "*.txt"`; do
   # $f should now be dir1/subdir1/file.txt
   # I want to copy it to dir2/subdir1/file.txt
   # the next line coveys the idea, but does not work
   # I'm attempting to substitute "dir1" with "dir2" in $f,
   # and store the new path in tmp.txt
   echo `sed -i "s/$SRC/$DST/" $f` > tmp.txt
   # Do the copy
   cp -f $f `cat tmp.txt`
done
```

Comment: Did you try: `man cp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `rsync`. This answer is based from this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only).

```
rsync -av --include='*.txt' --include='*/' --exclude='*' dir1/ dir2/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have `.txt` files in dir1, this would work:

```
cp -R dir1/* dir2/
```

But if you have other file extensions, it will copy them too. In this case, this will work:

```
cd /path/to/dir1
cp --parents `find . -name '*.txt'` path/to/dir2/
```

Comment: The first will copy ALL the files. I just want to copy the *.txt files between the two directories. With second answer, I'll need to provide the path/to/dir2. NOT the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: How could you copy a file without providing the destination folder? `/path/to/dir2` is just the root folder, I did not wrote `/path/to/dir2/and/all/subfolders/.../.../`

Comment: I want sed or awk to do it, just by replacing "dir1" with "dir2" in my example. I'll edit my post to elaborate more.